# Call procedure without full name

Tags: tcl

I have written 2 packages :
First package :

```
# firstpackage.tcl
namespace eval mypackage::firstpackage {}
proc mypackage::firstpackage::myproc {} {
    # ...
}
package provide mypackage::firstpackage 1.0
```

Second package :

```
# secondpackage.tcl
namespace eval mypackage::secondpackage {}
proc mypackage::secondpackage::myproc {} {
    # ...
}
package provide mypackage::secondpackage 1.0
```

I'm calling these 2 packages at once, like this :

```
# mypackage.tcl
package require mypackage::firstpackage 1.0
package require mypackage::secondpackage 1.0

package provide mypackage 1.0
```

Now when I call `mypackage 1.0` I don't want to call the full name of my procedure like this :

```
package require mypackage
# set myvar [mypackage::firstpackage::myproc] works...
set myvar [firstpackage::myproc]
```

I thought it was possible... But I have this error : *invalid command name "firstpackage::myproc"*
I tried to use `namespace export myproc` in my 2 files (firstpackage.tcl & secondpackage.tcl) or `namespace export *` in mypackage.tcl but without success...
Is there a way to call my procedure without full name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main ways.

1. Use `namespace export myproc` *inside* the `namespace eval`, and then `namespace import mypackage::firstpackage::myproc` in the context where you wish to use it.
2. Do `namespace path mypackage::firstpackage` in your using context so that commands are additionally looked up there. (By default, all namespaces only look for commands in themself and the global namespace; `namespace path` inserts between those two.)

It's *not recommended* to do either `namespace import` or `namespace path` (on the global namespace) as part of a package definition; let the consuming code do that as that's the actual code that owns the target context. Basically, the global namespace is the application's namespace and, by convention and history only, the Tcl language's namespace as well. Library code should not normally directly make changes to the global namespace (with a few exceptions such as Tk widget instances).

Comment: It works with `namespace path mypackage` but not with `namespace path mypackage::firstpackage` Do you have any idea ? and `namespace export myproc` inside the `namespace eval` + `namespace import mypackage::firstpackage::myproc` in my context doesn't work. another idea ?

Comment: @Mkn The `namespace path` is a single list of namespaces; if you use it twice (for a particular namespace) then it _replaces._